# Checking whether it is integer or not.

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I'm trying to prove following term is integer  for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N} :$

$$\frac{2^{m+n-1}\prod\limits_{k=1}^m(4k-3)\prod\limits_{l=1}^n(4l-1)}{(m+n)!}$$

I checked that if $m=n$ then this term is an integer, but I don't have any idea how to prove this.

I am trying to input many integers and still it is an integer.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Do you mean $\Pi$ (as in the product) instead of $\pi$?

Comment: oh Yes!. I am not accustomed to type math signs. Thank you for editing

Comment: I assume the products aren't nested

Comment: um.. if m is much larger than n then, two prods on top cannot cover all the odd integers up to m+n,; so we need to assume the m or n is much larger than the other one.

Comment: The odd factors are $(-1)^m\Pi_{k=-m+1}^n(4k-1)$

Comment: Can you show that the highest power of $p$ in $\Pi_{k=1}^{m+n}(A+4k)$ (for odd $A$) is at least as big as the highest power of $p$ in $(m+n)!$?

Comment: Do you mean A is fixed for k or A may change for k?

Comment: $A$ is fixed (and equals $-1-4m$)

Comment: If I succeed the statement you gave, then the key idea is we account the prime factors between up and down sides, and we can check up side's highest power of p is at least as big as the highest power of p in down side. Is it right?